# JavaFX error initializing ES2Pipeline on Debian Wheezy

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a JavaFX 8 project which relies heavy on transitions and other effects. My target platform is a barebone with an Intel Atom CPU running Debian Wheezy.
I searched for an answer all day long now but I cannot enable JavaFX OpenGL rendering.

Some outputs:

```
trr@m:~/$ java -Dprism.verbose=true -jar app.jar
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
...
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
        succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory
Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline: error initializing pipeline com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline

trr@m:~/$ lspci -v -s 00:02.0
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device 0d77
    ...
    Kernel driver in use: i915

trr@m:~/$ glxinfo
...
direct rendering: Yes
...
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) IGD 
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 8.0.5
```

glxgears shows ~59FPS all the time.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am using JavaFX on an eeePC 901.
I get very slow preformance and simular error messages:

```
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using platform text rasterizer
Using java-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory
Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline: error initializing pipeline com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
 vsync: true vpipe: false
```

lspci is giving:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GME Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27ae] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:830f]
        Kernel driver IN USE: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML     Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27a6] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:830f]
```

So I am using the i915 driver as well.